# Create menu (navigation menu ) with semi circle at right

Tags: html, wordpress, css, menu

I have been trying to Create menu (navigation menu ) with semi circle at right like the image attached.

I have been able to achieve the semi circle but while hovering and while its in current state its not showing it correctly

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0c84cxigbb

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the png image with semi circle that you want and set it as background image for hover and current menu_item class like

```
.menu_class ul .current_page_item a:hover, .menu_class ul li a:hover, .menu_class ul .current_page_parent a:hover { background: url("imageloacation") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
color: #ffffff; }
```

Comment: Can we do that in css3 instead of using an image ?